# Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string "True". VB.net

Tags: vb.net

While using the given below code showing one error. the error is: `Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string "True"`. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code :

```
cmd1.CommandText = "select * FROM attendance where academic_year='" & yearTextBox.Text & "' and School_Name='" & courseDropDownList.Text & "' and Class='" & semesterDropDownList.Text & "' and batch='" & batchDropDownList.Text & "' and hour='" & DropDownList6.Text & "' and date_present='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
sdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
While sdr1.Read
  dr("student_name") = sdr1("student_name")
  dr("rollnumber") = sdr1("roll_number")
  dr("comment") = sdr1("comment")
Dim status As String = ""
  If sdr1("present") = "True" Then // ***Error popup here***
     status = "Present"
  ElseIf sdr1("Absent") = "True" Then
     status = "Absent"
  ElseIf sdr1("od") = "True" Then
     status = "OD"
  End If
  If sdr1("late") = "True" Then
     dr("status_late") = ", Latecomer"
  End If
     dr("status") = status
     dt.Rows.Add(dr)
     dr = dt.NewRow
End While
sdr1.Close()
```

Comment: break and see what values comes is `sdr1("Present")` .probably if its null,use `.tostring` there.

Comment: or check `Isdbnull` before using comparison operator.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing this laboriously through code when SQL can do the work for you:

```
select
    student_name,
    roll_number,
    comment,
    CASE
       WHEN present='true' THEN 'present'
       WHEN absent ='true' THEN 'absent'
       WHEN od='true' THEN 'od'
    END as status,
    CASE
       WHEN late ='true' THEN ', Latecomer'
    END as status_late
FROM attendance where academic_year=@year
```

And also switch to using [parameterized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) queries to supply `@year` rather than constructing strings together.

If you make the above change, you may also be able to switch to directly [filling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx) your `DataTable` with the result set rather than using `ExecuteReader` and looping and copying the results across.

Comment: the problem is, that many programmers do not understand SQL and then make the fuzzy logic in the client

Answer (score 1):

it means one of the retrieved value is `NULL` in the DB, therefore you get a value of type `DBNull`. you should first check whether the retrieved value is `NOT NULL` using `.IsDBNull`, then you can compare it using `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when reading data from the database, you must ensure that the value being read is nullable or compulsory.

For Nullable value, you are not allow to set it into a string for example.
So, the best way when reading data from a database, you need to check for `IsDBNull` before setting the value, as follows;

```
If (sdr1("present") IsNot DBNull.Value) AndAlso sdr1("present") = "True" Then 
     status = "Present"
ElseIf (sdr1("Absent") IsNot DBNull.Value) AndAlso sdr1("Absent") = "True" Then
     status = "Absent"
ElseIf (sdr1("od") IsNot DBNull.Value) AndAlso sdr1("od") = "True" Then
     status = "OD"
End If

If (sdr1("late") IsNot DBNull.Value) AndAlso sdr1("late") = "True" Then
     dr("status_late") = ", Latecomer"
End If
```